# CSRF token mismatch error, Laravel 5.3/VueJS2

Tags: ajax, csrf, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm trying to get the Auth portion of an application I'm building done. I'm using Laravel 5.3 and VueJs 2 as my JS framework. 
In my login component, I have something along the lines of this.

```
<template>
    <form @submit="test" method="POST" action="/test">
        <input v-model='input' type='text'>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: {
                    input: "hello"
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        },
        methods: {
            test: function() {
                this.$http.post('/test', {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I also have the CSRF token set as metadata in the head of my HTML document.
`<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Laravel 5.3's Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken spits the error out, saying there is a token mismatch.
I'm currently var_dumping out all the $request info that gets passed into this class' `handle()` function.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        var_dump($request);
        if (
            $this->isReading($request) ||
            $this->runningUnitTests() ||
            $this->shouldPassThrough($request) ||
            $this->tokensMatch($request)
        ) {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }
        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }
```

I don't see the CSRF token being passed with the ajax request I'm sending. What's odd is that if I don't use ajax and do a normal form submit such as `{{csrf_field()}}` inside the form tags, the middleware successfully auths the token. This leads me to believe this is a problem with ajax/vue-resource that I'm using. I may be doing something wrong but I've scoured google posts/stackoverflow/youtube videos about this issue but nothing's fixed the error. I've done a workaround where I force a XSRF-TOKEN cookie to be compared to the token but this makes me think about security issues and what happens when a user accidentally or unknowingly deletes their cookies while using the application. Not sure if that would cause errors but I've talked to other devs/engineers and they say its not a good idea to force the cookie to be compared in the middleware instead of a CSRF_TOKEN.

Here are some other things I've tried.

```
//I've tried the vue.http.interceptors method that comes with the bootstrap.js file Laravel generates for vue js 2.
Vue.http.interceptors() //something along those lines
//Setting ajax setup in bootstrap.js as wel

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

//I've also tried sending the token along with the vue-resource post request in the Vue component method as well.

methods: {
  test: function() {
    this.$http.post('/test', {headers: 'X-CSRF-TOKEN: $('meta[name='_token']'.attr('content')}
    ).then(response => console.log(response));
  }
}

//I've also tried using axios as my http client as well.
```

Any advice or insight on why this may be occurring and how to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I would install Laravel Passport (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport)

This essentially adds everything you need to do authentication via Vue on the front end.

It also adds oAuth support to your app meaning that users can generate an API key and use their own clients to consume your API (should you want to do that).